# How can it be that those vectors form a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $X$ and $Y$ be $m \times  n$ matrices related by a linear transformation $P$ such that $Y=PX$. Is it true that rows of $P$ are a set of new basis vectors for expressing the columns of $X$? I find this statement quite weird, because obviously not always the rows of a $m \times n$ matrix form a basis. [Source, page 3](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.1100v1.pdf).

Comment: What do you mean "related by a lin. trans."?

Comment: It's worth noting that this comes from a paper called "A Tutorial on Principal Component Analysis" and that this particular step of the explanation has already been cast as a change of basis for an $m$-dimensional data set. This restricts the kinds of transformation that might be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P$ is an $m\times m$ invertible matrix whose rows (columns) form a basis in $\mathbb{R}^m$ due to their linear independence.

Comment: How do you know $P$ is invertible? It can just be any square matrix. Not all square matrices are invertible I guess.

Comment: A linear transformation is always assumed invertible. If that is not the case then there is no one-to-one correspondence between $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: So ideally it should be in the text that $P$ is invertible.

Comment: Yes if you look in the main paper this property is used e.g. in section V.

Comment: In section V rows of $P$ are made of eigenvectors of covariance matrix of $X$. Theorem 4 in appendix A proves these eigenvectors are orthogonal. If we have a matrix with rows made of orthogonal eigenvectors, is it necessarily an orthogonal matrix (definition says both rows and columns should be orthogonal). And therefore our matrix is orthogonal thus invertible.

Comment: Is that right??

Comment: This is correct. If the rows of $U$ denoted by $u_1,\ldots,u_n$  are orthogonal then $UU^*=\mathbb{I}$. The orthogonality assumption ensures invertibility (they form a basis) and therefore $U^{-1}=U^*$. Hence we also have $U^*U=\mathbb{I}$ which means that the columns are also orthogonal.

Comment: Actually, does it matter that $P$ is invertible? If matrix forms a basis, then it is invertible. But does it work in the opposite direction?

Comment: Yes, if $P$ is invertible then the only solution of the equation $\lambda^TP=0$ with $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\lambda=0$ (you can see this if you right multiply with $P^{-1})$. Hence, the $n$ rows of the matrix are linearly independent and form a basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Suppose we didn't require linear transformations to be invertible matrices. How to think of such a linear transformation? If the matrix is invertible, then we could possibly map two distinct points on a plane to a single point? It can't happen if the transformation matrix is invertible? And there's no way to revert this, right?

Comment: Correct. Assume the mappings of two points $y_i=Px_i$ ($i=1,2$). Then, they can be mapped to the same point $y_1=y_2$ if $P(x_2-x_1)=0$. If $P$ is invertible then $x_1=x_2$ else $x_2=x_1+a v$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ with vector $v$ the eigenvector that corresponds to the zero eigenvalue. If $P$ is not invertible infinite number of points can be mapped to the same point!

Comment: Not quite sure if I follow your reasoning. They can be mapped to the same point $y_1 = y_2$ if $P$ times the difference $x_2 - x_1$ is zero? You subtract vetor $x_1$ from $x_2$, transform it and get zero. What does it mean I got zero there? Does every linear transformation map zero vector to a zero vector?

Comment: What I wrote was that all the points $x_2(a)=x_1+a v$ parametrized by $a$   for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $v$ the eigenvector that corresponds to the zero eigenvalue of $P$ are mapped to $y_1$ since  $y_2-y_1=P(x_2-x_1)=0$. The answer to  the last question  is certainly yes. The zero is invariant under a linear transformation $P$.

Comment: If you don't mind, I asked a question about it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211151/invertible-and-non-invertible-linear-transformation Maybe you would like to answer?

Answer (score 0):

yes,the rows of matrix are not always form the basis,but only when you consider the rows of matrix as basis,you can understand the multiplication of matrics better,namely,under this circumstance,we will ignore wheather those basis are linearly dependent or not